# how to remove data from local db (sqlite) using code behind wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I want to do something like when user click a button then it will remove data from database ( it will only have one data every time user run the system). the problem is I try to use this code to remove the data but it does not work.

```
public void RemoveOrder(Order order)
    {
     try
        {

            using (tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext db = new tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext ())
            {

                db.Orders.Remove(order);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
            customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
        }

}
```

when I try to add the data to database using the same code but only change the `remove` to `Add` it working fine. but only with this remove thing it does not work.

[image: the <code>order</code> is not empty because when I put a breakdown it show exactly all the data inside the table]

Comment: where is the order object coming from?

Comment: @AnsonFong I've updated my question. `Order` is my table inside my database.

Comment: It is possible that the order object is not in orders in tempDBContext. Let's try to query the order object first and perform a delete action? The order object you passed in maybe not the same as tempDBContext. I always query and get the object from the DbContext and perform delete/update action.

Comment: @AnsonFong I don't know what to do. As I show in the picture that I've updated the `order` contains all the data from the table but still it does not delete the row when this `remove` execute.

Comment: Do you have a primary key for the order object? Can you show the primary key?

Comment: @AnsonFong `OrderId` is my primary key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190335/discussion-between-anson-fong-and-rayna-qarla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this and it should work:

```
public void RemoveOrder(Order order)
{
 try
    {

        using (tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext db = new tempPosOrderPaymentDBContext ())
        {
            var orderInDb = db.Orders.First(x=> x.OrderId == order.OrderId);
            db.Orders.Remove(orderInDb);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
        customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
    }
```

}